# Installing LibreOffice 4.0.1 on Fedora 17

Tags: installation, fedora, libreoffice

I downloaded 'LibreOffice_4.0.1.2_Linux_x86-64_rpm.tar.gz' from official site of libreoffice and follow the readme to install.

The installation completed successfully, but when I entered 'libreoffice' in the terminal, it gave an infomation:

> "no suitable windowing system found, existing"

Besides, when I click the icon in the application menu, nothing happened...

Does anyone meet the same problem? How to install the latest libreoffice 4.0.1 in fedora 17?

Comment: At least with previous versions, the command to launch it has been `soffice` (that's the old Star Office heritage showing through). Did you try that?

Answer (score 1):

first off, don't get the program via binary, this is hard to keep working and up to date, especially when it's already available in the package repos.

do:

```
sudo yum remove openoffice*
sudo yum install libreoffice
```

EDIT: As commenters mentioned, this will install the 3.6.x tree from the repos. If you really want to run the 4.x then you will need to fix your environment to support it instead.

```
sudo yum install pixman -y
```

Enjoy.

Comment: [Looks to me like this will currently get you a version of LibreOffice 3.5.7 on F17](https://admin.fedoraproject.org/updates/libreoffice?_csrf_token=58afa61a879a18b0f89113e9f9d8b1228b8952ef), which while hardly ancient is still a pretty far cry from 4.0.1.

Comment: its still a ton easier and it will be updated eventually once the fedora team gets it worked out for packaging. The OP didn't specify he/she was specifically looking for that release, but that they wanted libre office installed on Fedora -- this is the conventional way to go about doing that. None-the-less, I'll edit m original post to include the fix to get 4.x going on Fedora 17.

Comment: @SnakeDoc Unfortunately, you misunderstood my intention. I DO want to install the latest 4.0.1 version, because of Libreoffice [Impress Remote](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.libreoffice.impressremote&feature=search_result&hl=en).

Comment: @booksee see my last command above "yum install pixman" should do the trick

Comment: it does not work...it says that pixman-0.28.0-1.fc17.x86-64 is the latest version, nothing to be done

Answer (score 0):

only this command works for installing libreoffice manually but you can install it while you are installing the the os by selecting the part (`office use and development`) then it will be already installed in your platform

yum install libreoffice